# Using mod_rewrite to work with a custom string

Tags: string, url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite everything that uses this pattern...

`/test/?TEXT=TRUE` and allow it to be `/test/TEXT` AND `/test/TEXT2`, and so on.

Comment: The question is not vary clear. what about the second part of the query (=true,=random)? can you give some better examples?

Comment: You can use `RewriteCond` to match a regexp group on the query string, then use that matched group in your `RewriteRule`

Comment: It's pretty clear actually. The last sentence sums it all up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Create 2 rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/test/help$  /test/?help=true [L]
RewriteRule ^/test/(.*)$  /test/?random=$1
```

Comment: I already know the first rule. The second rule doesn't work at all. I want the first part ?random to be the new url test/"random"

Comment: No, because with the first rule you tell the server that whenever /test/help is called it should stop matching with other rules by the [L] (last) flag. The next rule will fetch all requests made to /test/whatever-is-provided. Via $_GET['random'] you can fetch the provided data.

Comment: Upd. what is your purpose then? I'm guessing you want to include a file somewhere.. which is now possible when using `$_GET['random']`

Comment: I don't want 50 lines of code in my htaccess for rewrites?  I want to change the url to the first part, "random" since =$1 will be =true.

Comment: Random, that's exactly what's possible with `(.*)`??

Comment: And if i now, finally understand what you're trying to do. You can still do this? In your code create a new $_GET value based on $_GET['random']... Where do you need it for? Because it's a bit vague to me..

Comment: "random" is supposed to refer to a random function in my list... not the word literally... which is why I was puzzled. I have numerous $_GET values that I want to use.

Comment: RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /test/?$1=true [L] is what I'm trying to do! Get it?

Comment: Yes I get it, i think. You can manipulate your URL by setting `RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$  /test/?function=$1&flag=true`. Now you know which function is called and you can instantiate that function by `$functionOutput = $_GET["function"]();`